# Create master page at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke, master-pages

Hi 
I want to create a master page dynamically by the user like the one DotNetNuke is done
and load the modules where the user needs. I also want to have nested master pages with the above approach. 
Please help me design the above problem.

Comment: and I want to go moon :)

Comment: sure KMan helped me in this tour !

Answer (score 2):

Checkout:

- [Really Dynamic Master Pages](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamicmaster.aspx)
- [Nested Master Pages](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/nested-master-pages-cs)
- [Nested ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke has a very permissive open source license.  You can use the Skin code from DNN in your own projects.  Get the source [here](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).